# Rails basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am relatively new to rails and right now I am developing a simple log in log out system.

In my app when I log in the URL generated is:

localhost:3000/user/index/7

When I log out I get back to the root. But if copy this URL and paste it in another browser window i get instantly logged in without being directed to the log in form. How to correct this issue.

I tried to store user id in session hash and then upon logout i have set user id in session to be nil. But that does not work. Help needed.